# Expected value of infinite sequence of dice rolls.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

An infinite sequence of events occurs as follows: $n_i$ dice are rolled. The resulting sum is $n_{i+1}$. If $n_i=1$, then the sum is just the number rolled. Given $n_0=1$, what is the probability 3 appears somewhere in the sequence, and what is the expected value of $n_i$, for each $i$, and does the sequence grow exponentially? I.e., $n_i>k^i$ for sufficiently large $i$ and a constant $k>1$?

I think that the probability three appears should just be 1 because the sequence is infinite, but I'm not sure how to prove this.

For the expected values, $\mathbb{E}[n_0] = \frac{7}{2}$, and $\mathbb{E}[n_1] = \mathbb{E}[\text{one dice roll}] \cdot \mathbb{E}[n_0]$ = $\left( \frac{7}{2} \right)^2$, and $\mathbb{E}[n_i] = \left( \frac{7}{2} \right)^i$ by linearity of expectation. I'm not sure about this part.

If the expected value is true, based off of that can't I say the sequence grows exponentially, since the expected values do?

Answer (score 1):

The probability that $3$ appears somewhere is not exactly $1$! Once $4$ or a higher number appears, $3$ will never appear again. So we can model the situation as a Markov chain with four states, two of which absorb. $>3$ means "$3$ will definitely not appear in the sequence".

[image]

This has transition matrix
$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}
1/6&0&0&0\\
1/6&1/36&0&0\\
1/6&1/18&1&0\\
1/2&11/12&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

where the rows/columns represent states $1,2,3,>3$ in order. $V_\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}Q^n(1,0,0,0)^T$ gives the probabilities of ultimately ending up in states $3$ and $>3$. Diagonalising, we get
$$V_\infty=(0,0,37/175,138/175)^T$$
so the probability that $3$ appears in the sequence is $\frac{37}{175}$.

Your solutions to the other two parts of the question are OK.